# Wordpress API Customization

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest

we have an Educational websites built with Wordpress, which shows and previews it is content as categories and subcategories, depending  on Educational Semester, Grade and subject.
Recently, we needed to integrate this use content with another educational website using an API.
the default API returns an out put of 9 posts only, with more not needed details, on the other hand I need only about 4 outputs of the API to be used on the other website.
In the Attached image is the output of the API, and my questions are:

**1) where can I find the API code file to be edited?
2) how to customize it to get only these fields ( id, Title, Grade, Subject, Link, Ctegories and SubCategories[image] )?
3) how to get all the published posts not only 9 posts as shown in the attached image?
**

thank you so much

the attached photo shows the output with extra detailed fields. where I need to minimize them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mqmj.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mqmj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to change the response you get from a call to https://www.it-mohe.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, which is a call to the WordPress REST API, is that right?

WordPress allows global parameters to be specified on the URI in the querystring.

e.g. https://www.it-mohe.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,title,grade

See WordPress documentation on how: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/

The WordPress API limits the response to 10 posts by default. You can page the results and specify a maximum of 100 records per page.

See WordPress documentation on how: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Comment: Thnx alot dear David, will check every detail in your sweet answer. Appreciated.

Comment: thanks, but where can i find the REST API code to edit?  I mean  in which file or location in the wp folder?

Comment: Which API? The WordPress API? Have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/. If that doesn't do enough for you, you could look at writing an adapter to sit in front of it that provides what you want. i.e. don't expect to be able to edit the WordPress API code.

Comment: Also look at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/client-libraries/